# Sending e-mail based on combo box dropdown selection in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, workflow, email

As far as capability, is SharePoint 2010 capable of doing the following?

User selects combo box dropdown value in one of the fields on a SharePoint List.
Lets call this field, Status.

If Status gets defined as Submitted, then email should be generated to XXX indicating that there are issues ready for review that are in submitted State.

If Status gets defined as Proposed, then email should be generate to YYY indicating that there are issues ready for review that are in Proposed State.

Is this possible to do? If so, please point me in right direction.

As a further bonus, is it possible for SharePoint to somehow find the boss of the person who sets the status as Proposed, and send him or her the email (instead of a set address YYY)? This might be done if SharePoint can reference Outlook and look at the hierarchy structure...(or if the network domain has that information, I don't know...).  This second one is harder, but if it is possible, let me know on that one too.

Answer (score 1):

Use SharePoint Designer to create a workflow that will send email notifications. You can have the workflow kickoff on item creation or modification. The workflow can check your status field and run actions based on its value.

As far as the manager of a user. In sharepoint designer workflow there should be action called "Lookup Manager of User." You can then set the user to created by.